# How to set alignment for UIScrollView in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiscrollview

i am creating an application, where i am using UIScrollView for displaying the number of available colors of each product. I am getting number of available colors at run time, so i have used for loop and displaying on my scroll view. Its working fine, but the problem if i am getting only one available color then my output is coming as below screen :

[image]

But the output should be as below screen :

[image]

It seems like i need to do kind of center alignment for my UIScrollView, so every available color will suppose to display from center. here is my code :

```
UIScrollView *availableColorScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
availableColorScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
availableColorScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
availableColorScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
availableColorScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayAvlbleColors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 23 * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = availableColorScrollView.frame.size;
    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 14, 16, 16)];
    [label.layer setCornerRadius:8];

    NSString *strColorCode = [arrayAvlbleColors objectAtIndex:i];
    strColorCode = [strColorCode substringFromIndex:1];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:strColorCode]];
    [subview addSubview:label];
    [availableColorScrollView addSubview:subview];
}

 [self.view addSubview:availableColorScrollView];

availableColorScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(24 * arrayAvlbleColors.count, availableColorScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Please suggest me to achieve my output, Thanks!

Comment: You've to implement your own logic. Its not possible technically.

Comment: I am not getting logic for my problem, thats why i have asked this.. can you please tell me how this logic should be, can we set offset for scrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the simple answer but working fine if u taken any `Mainview` or `subview` or else,
set the `frame size/2` for `height` and `width` it automatically set it into `center` of the  `subview`.

here i used static color , customize urself

just change your line this

```
 NSString *strColorCode = [arrayAvlbleColors objectAtIndex:i];
strColorCode = [strColorCode substringFromIndex:1];
[label setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:strColorCode]];
[subview addSubview:label];
[availableColorScrollView addSubview:subview];
```

into

```
    NSString *strColorCode = [arrayAvlbleColors objectAtIndex:i];
     strColorCode = [strColorCode substringFromIndex:1];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[self colorWithHexString:strColorCode]];

    //use any one

    //option no 1:

    //[label setCenter:subview.center];

     //option no 2:

    [ label setCenter:CGPointMake(subview.frame.size.width / 2, subview.frame.size.height / 2)];


    [subview addSubview:label];
    [availableColorScrollView addSubview:subview];
```

final out put is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate your scrollview content to be placed in centre like this:

```
float contentWidth = 23 * arrayAvlbleColors.count;
```

Now you have content width to subtract from scrollView's width

```
float centerPadding = 0.0f;
float width = availableColorScrollView.frame.size.width;
centerPadding = width - contentWidth;
if(centerPadding < 0)
{
   //content cannot be placed in center as content is bigger than width
   centerPadding = 0.0f;
}
```

We have padding to center our content in scrollView, so use it in for loop like this :

```
frame.origin.x = (23 * i) + centerPadding;
```

Comment: Thanks @Prince for giving me response.. i have applied your code but i am not getting any color also. Do you want me to post my code over here..?